# (How) should we mark the 10th anniversary of SFF.SE?

Tags: discussion

Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange [started](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1/31394) on **11 January 2011**, which means the site is less than two months away from being ***a decade old!*** That's a pretty big milestone, so do we, as a community, want to mark the occasion with any special events or celebrations?

Word from SE is that we can get a special temporary birthday banner, looking something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJAbc.jpg) (image from Ask Ubuntu, which turned 10 years old a few months ago). I don't know how much more we can get on the design/support side of things, but certainly we're able to organise community events if there's enough interest.

Links from other sites' metas that recently turned 10, if you need inspiration:

- [Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/10th-anniversary)
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13049)

I'm posting this pretty early, two months ahead of the birthday date, because of the impending holiday period: I guess fewer people will be actively using SE during most of the weeks leading up to 11 January. Also it gives us more time to discuss and brainstorm different ideas.

Comment: Not to seem ungrateful, but can we ask for a banner that looks less like it belongs on Geocities circa 1996?

Comment: @Valorum I don't actually know how much it's customisable. Something that fits with our own site theme would be nice, if possible. I'll ask.

Comment: Don't look to the Physics site for inspiration; over there we have done jack squat.

Comment: Probably some banner that belongs on Neocities circa 2077 would be a better fit :p Also consider playing cross-site (SE) puzzles and trivia quizzes with folks from Puzzling, Board games, TV&Anime and Arqade in chat and on discords (off-site).

Comment: Maybe SE can finally reward this achievement by giving us back a proper theme.

Comment: Delete the whole site?

Comment: @Möoz or rather, create a paradox (preferably involving a time-traveling robot), causing the entire site to never have existed.

Comment: @SQB Maybe that's what the Angle of Death has been all along.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Is one hundred degrees the Angle of Death?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I believe so yes, does that also mean "Angle of Death" is the "Typo of Annoyance"?

Comment: The Angle of Death is a Pedant too? Go figure.

Comment: [Another site with a recent tenth anniversary.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4896/how-shall-we-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-tenth-birthday)

Comment: We could all watch the Star Wars Holiday Special, and then contemplate the possibility that we've collectively managed to create something even worse. (I kid, of course — my nonsense excluded, this community is great.)

Comment: Watch the 50th anniversary Doctor Who special?

Comment: Watch the tenth episode of all of the Star Treks?

Comment: I think the Top 10 Users should give away 10,000k rep in bounties!

Comment: @Skooba 10k or 10,000k?

Comment: Every active member deserves a vacation in the Caribbean. I could have sponsored if COVID-19 situation wasn't there.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Does SE offer rep loans?

Comment: "Very well, thank you"

Comment: Alas, ten years is far too short a time to live among such excellent and admirable users. I don't know half of you half as well as I should like, and I like less than half of you half as well as you deserve!

Comment: Please no temporary birthday banner. I hate those due to some bad experiences elsewhere.

Comment: @lfurini Lol, the only valid response IMO.

Comment: @Buzz you could at least have had a banner saying "1×10¹ years and counting".

Comment: OK.

I probably shouldn't have posted this, but when someone is MAD about Isaac Asimov, you probably won't forget his birthday on 2nd January 2021, specially when he is turning ***100 years*** on the same date! People have posted many comments, all talking about movies (Star Trek and Star Wars) and other amazing stuff (Doctor Who!), but forgetting the masterminds behind the success these franchises. The Creators. Isaac Asimov was a great Sci-Fi writer. He wrote many bestsellers and books with themes that still inspire the writers of today.

Comment: Cont. - If there is someone who deserves to be honoured on this occasion, it is him. On this grand occasion of Sci-fi SE turning 1 x 10^1 years, (credit @PaulD.Waite) it IS quite a great coincidence Isaac Asimov turning 1 x 10^2 years!

Comment: @AyushBhatt I really like Asimov's article "[The Relativity of Wrong](https://chem.tufts.edu/AnswersInScience/RelativityofWrong.htm)". It helped me feel more comfortable with science and uncertainty.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, we really share similar thoughts!

Comment: @AyushBhatt Isn't that 101, not 100? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov) says he was born in January **1920**.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - My bad!

Comment: Unless you **unfreeze Mos** I ain't gonna show up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, what we did in the end amounts to the following:

- A commemorative [blog post](https://thesffblog.com/2021/01/science-fiction-fantasy-stack-exchange-10th-anniversary/) written by our very own blog admin [Jack B Nimble](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1148/jack-b-nimble), including one-liners from various site users (currently 10, including moderators, high-rep users, former moderators, and former high-rep users) expressing their views on the site over the years.
- [Starting up](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394) a new topic challenge program, kicking it off in the ten-year anniversary month with the topic of [Isaac Asimov](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13230/31394) and his works. In its first week, the [call for proposals for future topic challenges](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394) has already attracted 7 answers from 5 different users.

That's pretty much it, I think (I'm writing this on 15 January 2021, four days after the anniversary date). Not a *massive* celebration, but a nice recognition for this significant milestone.

Here's to the next ten years!