# January 2021 Topic Challenge: Isaac Asimov

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

Welcome to 2021, a new year with new possibilities for SFF.SE. As the site approaches its tenth birthday this month, I'm happy to announce the first of a brand-new series of **topic challenges**, encouraging the site's community to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. The first topic challenge is going to be devoted to one of the most famous sci-fi authors of them all, whose 101st birthday is also this month:

### the works of Isaac Asimov.

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during January 2021 we should all try to: either read some works of Asimov and ask interesting questions about them, or ask questions about Asimov stories we've read before, or help out by *answering* other people's Asimov questions.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13231/31394). We'll keep a list of all Asimov questions asked during January 2021 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous. There might be bounties though ...

Useful Asimov-related resources include:

- [Asimov Online](http://www.asimovonline.com/asimov_home_page.html), "a comprehensive collection of resources pertaining to Isaac Asimov".
- [Free SF Online](https://www.freesfonline.net/authors/Isaac_Asimov.html), an (incomplete?) list of Asimov stories freely and legally available online.
- *feel free to edit this meta post and add more stuff here*

---

**What's next?**

The current Asimov topic was chosen on the suggestion of [AyushBhatt](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13171/how-should-we-mark-the-10th-anniversary-of-sff-se#comment46536_13171), quite haphazardly at the last minute. I thought Asimov would be an easy "in" for people to get into topic challenges with, and he's arguably underappreciated on SFF.SE with "only" [144 non-ID questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isaac-asimov+-story-identification). Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

Comment: Not a new post for the topic challenge, but I've just started a bounty on [A story mentioning Isaac Asimov as a character](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3862/31394) in the hope that someone can find an answer this month. (Paging @user14111 ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [When was the origin of the "Nightfall" quotation found?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241435/when-was-the-origin-of-the-nightfall-quotation-found) by [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez), 03/01/2021.
- [Is Gregory Laborian a fictionalised version of Isaac Asimov?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/241456/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394), 04/01/2021.
- [What is the significance of the Olympics in the short story "Profession" by Isaac Asimov?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242223/what-is-the-significance-of-the-olympics-in-the-short-story-profession-by-isaa) by [therxv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/136210/therxv), 22/01/2021
- [What did Asimov find embarrassing about "Marooned Off Vesta”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242320/asimov-embarrassment-over-marooned-off-vesta) by [SuperCreff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/135790/supercreff), 24/01/2021
- [What is the significance of the name Azazel for Asimov's demon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/242620/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394), 31/01/2021.
- ...
- *add entries in the form `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/01/2021.`*

Plus ID questions which don't mention Asimov but whose answers turned out to be Asimov stories:

- [Book about an AI that traps people on a spaceship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/241621/31394) by [AyushBhatt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/133784/ayushbhatt), 08/01/2021.
- [Martians on Everest](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/241661/31394) by [SuperCreff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/135790/supercreff), 09/01/2021.

And two new answers, both by DavidW, to an old unanswered Asimov-related story-ID question on which I placed a bounty:

- [A story mentioning Isaac Asimov as a character](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3862/31394)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [When was the origin of the "Nightfall" quotation found?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/241435/31394), with a score of **29** at the end of January.

The **most viewed** is [What did Asimov find embarrassing about "Marooned Off Vesta”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/242320/31394), with approximately **5000** views during January.