# March 2021 Topic Challenge: Cornelia Funke

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the third of SFF.SE's new series of **topic challenges**, encouraging the site's community to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the March 2021 topic challenge is going to be devoted to [a contemporary German writer of children's fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornelia_Funke):

### the works of Cornelia Funke.

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during March 2021 we should all try to: either read some works of Cornelia Funke and ask interesting questions about them, or ask questions about some of her stories we've read before, or help out by *answering* other people's Cornelia Funke questions.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13281/31394). We'll keep a list of all Cornelia Funke questions asked during March 2021 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous. There might be bounties though ...

Here is [b_jonas](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4918/b-jonas)'s [original presentation](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13248/31394) of this proposal, with links added by me:

> A contemporary writer of children's fantasy.  Her most famous books are:
>
> - *Herr der Diebe* (2002, translated to English as [*The Thief Lord*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thief_Lord)), adapted to [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thief_Lord_(film)) in 2006;
> - *Drachenreiter* (2004, translated to English as [*Dragon Rider*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Rider_(novel))) and one sequel, adapted to [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Rider_(film)) in 2020;
> - *Tintenherz* (2003, translated to English as [*Inkheart*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkheart)) and its [three sequels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkheart_trilogy), plus a [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkheart_(film)) adaptation for the first book in 2008, there's also a [video game](http://www.gamefaqs.com/portable/ds/data/954949.html) adaptation.

Questions about adaptations of Funke books will also be considered as part of the topic challenge, even if they weren't overseen by Funke herself.

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Cornelia Funke answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of March, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [Was there any "official" word on the Inkheart film trilogy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/244400/57310) by [Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57310/skooba), 10/03/2021
- [Why is Death "the Great Shape-Changer" in "Inkheart"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/244530/33591) by [Mithical](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/33591), 13/03/2021
- [How many copies of Inkheart were printed/sold, in-universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/244703/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394), 17/03/2021
- [Was Fenoglio based on any real author?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/244770/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394), 18/03/2021
- [Where is the setting of the start of Dragon Rider?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245073/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394), 26/03/2021
- [Where do Meggie and Mo (and Elinor) live originally?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245143/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394), 28/03/2021
- ...
- *add entries in the form `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/03/2021.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Was Fenoglio based on any real author?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/244770/31394), with a score of **11** at the end of March.

The **most viewed** is [Where is the setting of the start of Dragon Rider?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245073/31394), with approximately **265** views during March, followed by [Why is Death "the Great Shape-Changer" in "Inkheart"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/244530/31394) with approximately **230** views.