# April 2021 Topic Challenge: David Weber (Honorverse)

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the fourth of SFF.SE's new series of **topic challenges**, encouraging the site's community to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the April 2021 topic challenge is going to be devoted to [an American writer of military sci-fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Weber):

### David Weber and his works, especially the Honorverse.

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during April 2021 we should all try to: either read some *Honorverse* books or other works of David Weber and ask interesting questions about them, or ask questions about some of those stories we've read before, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13311/31394). We'll keep a list of all David Weber / Honorverse questions asked during April 2021 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll award at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

Here is [Donald McLean](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5424/donald-mclean)'s [original presentation](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13258/31394) of this proposal:

> **David Weber and/or the Honorverse**
>
> One of the most popular military science fiction authors around, and yet neither he nor his best known series are properly represented on this site.

The original proposal didn't exactly specify the scope, so I've decided to err on the broad side. If someone posts about some of David Weber's sci-fi or fantasy books which aren't part of the Honorverse, we'll count that for the topic challenge too.

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The David Weber / Honorverse answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of April, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [Did Weber base People's Republic of Haven on post-revolution France?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245421/31394) by [DVK-on-Ahch-To](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk-on-ahch-to), 05/04/2021.
- [Did the Troll intend UK-Argentine war?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245438/31394) by [DVK-on-Ahch-To](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk-on-ahch-to), 05/04/2021.
- [Is each Hyper layer a discrete and singular space?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245480/31394) by [Jontia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40437/jontia), 06/04/2021.
- [How does Milla's blaster get re-charged?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245532/31394) by [DVK-on-Ahch-To](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk-on-ahch-to), 07/04/2021.
- [Are there efforts to retrieve any future tech from the Atlantic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245533/31394) by [DVK-on-Ahch-To](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk-on-ahch-to), 07/04/2021.
- [Did Trolls develop their own technology?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245758/31394) by [DVK-on-Ahch-To](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk-on-ahch-to), 12/04/2021.
- [Do any of Weber's other works explain what happened with the Roman Legion?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245761/31394) by [DVK-on-Ahch-To](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk-on-ahch-to), 12/04/2021.
- [Fate of Captain Wu of HMS Cometary](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245898/fate-of-captain-wu-of-hms-cometary) by [Jontia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40437/jontia), 16/04/2021.
- [Did the Mesan Alignment plot ever get a conclusion?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/246311/31394) by [Jontia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40437/jontia), 26/04/2021.
- [Why did Weber decide not to kill off Honor Harrington?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/246393/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394), 28/04/2021.
- ...
- *add entries in the form `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/04/2021.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these are [Did Weber base People's Republic of Haven on post-revolution France?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245421/31394) and [Is each Hyper layer a discrete and singular space?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245480/31394) and [Why did Weber decide not to kill off Honor Harrington?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/246393/31394), each with a score of **6** at the end of April.

The **most viewed** is [Did Weber base People's Republic of Haven on post-revolution France?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245421/31394), with approximately **197** views during April.