# Favorite Question and Answers from Second Quarter 2021

Tags: discussion, blog

Oops. A little late, but still good.

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from April 1st 2021 through June 30th 2021.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2021/04/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2021/04/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2021/04/01)

**I will be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter year. Also the [most controversial question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/550327/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site-by-start-date) of the quarter. Also a sum of all the [bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/618952/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) that were awarded.**

Additionally if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post has been made and submissions are now closed.

### [Blog](https://thesffblog.com/2021/08/favorite-question-and-answers-from-second-quarter-2021/)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late for the blog post, but wanted to have this recorded at least on meta.

### Topic challenges

The second quarter of 2021 saw the continuation of SFF.SE's [topic challenge program](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), with three topic challenges completed during this quarter: [David Weber / Honorverse](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13310/31394), [Margaret St. Clair](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13332/31394), and [Thaddeus Howze](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13347/31394).

- The April challenge was our most successful so far by question count, producing ten questions from three distinct users (DVK-on-Ahch-To, Jontia, Rand al'Thor). It was a hard choice, but my favourite was [Did Weber base People's Republic of Haven on post-revolution France?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245421/31394), where I awarded a bounty to Clara Diaz Sanchez's answer.
- The May challenge produced three questions from two distinct users (Rand al'Thor, Clara Diaz Sanchez). My favourite was [Meaning of acronym UNBI](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/246656/31394), where I'll award a bounty to Buzz's answer.
- The June challenge, our first inspired by an SFF.SE user who is also a writer, produced three questions from two distinct users (SQB, Rand al'Thor). Only one answer was posted to any of these questions, and I didn't award any bounty that month.