# July 2021 Topic Challenge: Rivers of London

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the seventh of SFF.SE's new series of **topic challenges**, encouraging the site's community to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the July 2021 topic challenge is going to be devoted to an ongoing [urban fantasy series starting from 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Grant_(book_series)):

### *Rivers of London*

### [rivers-of-london](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rivers-of-london)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during July 2021 we should all try to: either read *Rivers of London* (or not, if you've already read it) and ask interesting questions about it, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13422/31394). We'll keep a list of all *Rivers of London* questions asked during July 2021 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The *Rivers of London* answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of July, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Comment: This is actually [a large series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Grant_(book_series)) of stories, novels, and graphic novels, not a single novel.

Comment: @Spencer Sorry. Please feel free to edit my post accordingly; I don't have any first-hand experience of this story/series/franchise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brivers-of-london%5D+created%3A2021-07+is%3Aq) as part of this topic challenge**

- [How do all the short stories and graphic novels fit into the Rivers of London Timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251055/31394) by [Jontia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40437/jontia), 04/07/2021.
- [How big is the magical community in Rivers of London](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251124/58193) by [Jontia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40437/jontia), 06/07/2021.
- [Why was the title of Rivers of London changed to Midnight Riot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/252009/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394), 28/07/2021.
- [Could this be why Lesley did it?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/252116/) by [Spencer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/63330), 31/07/2021.
- [Is there a particular building on the real Russell Square that we can identify as the Folly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/252117/) by [Spencer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/63330), 31/07/2021.
- ...
- *add entries in the form `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/07/2021.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these, at the exact end of July in UTC, was [Why was the title of Rivers of London changed to Midnight Riot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252009/why-was-the-title-of-rivers-of-london-changed-to-midnight-riot) with a score of **7**, but it was rapidly overtaken (while it's still July somewhere in the world) by a late winner, [Is there a particular building on the real Russell Square that we can identify as the Folly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/252117/), with a score of **9** at the time of writing (around noon UTC on 1 August).

The **most viewed** is hard to determine: at the time of writing it's [Could this be why Lesley did it?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/252116/31394) with over **200** views, but this question went HNQ after the end of UTC July, so at that moment the most viewed might have been [Why was the title of Rivers of London changed to Midnight Riot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/252009/) and [How big is the magical community in Rivers of London](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251124/) might have been the winners at that moment, both with around **110** views.

Comment: Embarrassingly poor response for this one. My Bad.

Comment: @Jontia Not your fault! It's a great series, but not one that leaves lots of unanswered questions. That's a good sign - much better than a series filled with plot holes!

Comment: @Randal'Thor sorry to make it complicated.