# Favorite Question and Answers from Third Quarter 2021

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

All the data has been submitted to the post: [Favorite Question and Answers from Third Quarter 2021](https://thesffblog.com/2021/10/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-third-quarter-2021/)

### Origin

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from July 1st 2021 through September 30th 2021.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2021/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2021/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2021/07/01)

**I will be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter year. Also the [most controversial question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/revision/1483709/1819138/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site-by-start-date) of the quarter. Also a sum of all the [bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/revision/1483710/1819137/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) that were awarded.**

Additionally if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

Comment: I'm curious if there's a SEDE query that can show us the best *moderator* posts in the last quarter, on the main site of course, in the last quarter. If it helps our user-ids are 3804, 31936, 31394, 58193

Answer (score 2):

### Topic challenges

The third quarter of 2021 saw a bit of a low point (in its second half) in SFF.SE's [topic challenge program](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), with only two topic challenges completed during this quarter: [Rivers of London](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13421/31394) and [The Elder Scrolls](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13440/31394) (the latter run jointly with Arqade SE).

- The July challenge produced five questions from three distinct users (Jontia, Rand al'Thor, Spencer). My favourite *question* was [Is there a particular building on the real Russell Square that we can identify as the Folly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/252117/31394) (I love a good [real-location](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-location) question), but it remains unanswered, so instead I'm promoting [How do all the short stories and graphic novels fit into the Rivers of London Timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251055/31394), where I'll award a bounty to Jontia's answer.
- The August challenge was our first experiment at a joint topic challenge with a sister site, in this case [Arqade aka Gaming SE](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15955). This event produced only one SFF question (asked by nick012000) and two Arqade questions from two distinct users (Tyll'a, prince). The SFF question remains unanswered, so I didn't award any bounty in that topic challenge.
- There was no September challenge, because I was busy IRL and forgot to post one, and nobody else picked up the slack. Topic challenges will continue in the last quarter of 2021.

Answer (score 2):

These are my favorites that I've found today (a couple of months ago I might have had other favorites, which I've forgotten about since :-) ).

[A planet called Shayol/Treason](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252756/short-story-about-someone-who-is-exiled-on-a-prison-planet-where-some-people-bur/252764#comment693728_252764)

[This brilliant answer compiling and counting Asimov books, etc.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251485/how-many-books-did-isaac-asimov-write/251489#comment689397_251489)

I particularly like the two recent answers to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81769/help-identifying-a-story-where-kids-discover-some-kind-of-wormhole-in-a-garden#comment687861_81769) older question (what can I do if one of those two answers is mine :-)  ).  I hope the OP will look and respond...

Another great late answer - the accepted answer to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/198169/movie-like-body-snatchers-with-bus-and-cielito-lindo/251188#comment687395_251188) question was a great find.

I think [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250989/how-intelligent-is-the-doctor-compared-to-other-galifreyans/251040#251040) was one of the most fun.  The really correct answer would be a combination of the accepted answer and Pete's, but I guess neither of us wanted to poach.