# Topic challenge is taking a break in September, returning in October

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

Apologies that this has only come to light after the September topic challenge post should have been made, but it seems as though this has slipped through the cracks.

The moderation team plans to restart the topic challenge in October, so watch this space.

See the current voting on Topic Challenges [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13240/propose-future-topics-for-sff-topic-challenges).

Comment: The last couple of topic challenges don't seem to have provoked much interest. Perhaps we could use this interregnum to have a think about what and how we want these to proceed?

Comment: @Valorum We're all ears to suggestions, if you have any.

Comment: Taking a break in August might be something to learn. Vacation season probably contributed to the poor turn-out for the "Elder Scrolls" challenge. It's too late for this year, but it would be worth bearing in mind for future years.