# October 2021 Topic Challenge: Gene Wolfe

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the ninth of SFF.SE's new series of **topic challenges**, encouraging the site's community to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the October 2021 topic challenge is going to be devoted to a [prolific American writer of sci-fi and fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Wolfe):

### Gene Wolfe

### [gene-wolfe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gene-wolfe)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during October 2021 we should all try to: either read some Gene Wolfe stories and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13487/31394). We'll keep a list of all Gene Wolfe questions asked during October 2021 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Gene Wolfe answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of October, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [Is the Sante Croix officer actually Number Five's brother?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/254573/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor), 03/10/2021.
- [How clear is the geographical setting of the Book of the New Sun from the text?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/254809/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor), 09/10/2021.
- [What evidence is there that Severian encounters evidence of himself from the past?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254853/what-evidence-is-there-that-severian-encounters-evidence-of-himself-from-the-pas) by [Buzz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48874/buzz), 11/10/2021.
- [Was the backward-running time stream of the cacogens intended as an allusion to T. H. White's Merlyn?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254855/was-the-backward-running-time-stream-of-the-cacogens-intended-as-an-allusion-to) by [Buzz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48874/buzz), 11/10/2021.
- ["The Hero as Werwolf": why that spelling for werewolf?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/255487/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor), 30/10/2021.

---

The **highest-voted** and **most viewed** of these is ["The Hero as Werwolf": why that spelling for werewolf?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/255487/31394), with a score of **18** and approximately **1000** views at the end of October.