# November 2021 topic challenge: Samuel R. Delany

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the tenth of SFF.SE's new series of **topic challenges**, encouraging the site's community to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the November 2021 topic challenge is going to be devoted to an [American sci-fi author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_R._Delany):

### Samuel R. Delany

### [samuel-r-delany](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samuel-r-delany)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during November 2021 we should all try to: either read some Delany stories and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13509/31394). We'll keep a list of all Delany questions asked during November 2021 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Samuel R. Delany answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of November, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [In Samuel R. Delany’s Dhalgren, what catastrophe befell the city of Bellona?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/255579/31394) by [Silly but True](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/145218/silly-but-true), 01/11/2021.
- [Is Samuel R. Delany’s Wonder Woman an official part of Leiber Estate’s Fafhrd & the Gray Mouser continuity?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255552/is-samuel-r-delaney-s-wonder-woman-an-official-part-of-leiber-estate-s-fafhrd) by [Silly but True](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/145218/silly-but-true), 01/11/2021.
- An unserious train wreck joke: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255564/in-samuel-r-delaney-s-hogg-does-xxx-question-censored-for-profanity by [Silly but True](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/145218/silly-but-true), 01/11/2021.
- [In Samuel R. Delany’s Flight from Nevèrÿon, is its NYC intended to be a fictionalized version of the city?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/255621/31394) by [Silly but True](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/145218/silly-but-true), 02/11/2021.
- [Why does the Kid wear only one sandal?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255657/why-does-the-kid-wear-one-sandal) by [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez), 03/11/2021.
- [Are the Poems of Rydra Wong in Babel-17 based on the real works of Marilyn Hacker?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/256342/31394) by [David Siegel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/112520/david-siegel), 22/11/2021.
- [Are there reliable sources for the influence of Babel-17 on other SF using strong Sapir–Whorf?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256359/are-there-reliable-sources-for-the-influence-of-babel-17-on-other-sf-using-stron) by [David Siegel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/112520/david-siegel), 22/11/2021.
- [Was there any special reason why Samuel Delany’s The Star-Pit Radio Play Adaptation was played on radio at Thanksgiving for more than a decade?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256490/was-there-any-special-reason-why-samuel-delany-s-the-star-pit-radio-play-adaptat) by [Silly but True](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/145218/silly-but-true), 25/11/2021.
- [Authorship of "The Dying Castles"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256512/authorship-of-the-dying-castles) by [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez), 26/11/2021.
- [Do the events in Empire Star happen only once, the same way over and over, or slightly differently in different iterations?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256650/do-the-events-in-empire-star-happen-only-once-the-same-way-over-and-over-or-sl) by [Spencer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/63330/spencer), 30/11/2021.

---

The **highest-voted** and **most viewed** of these is [Why does the Kid wear only one sandal?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/255657/31394) by [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez), with a score of **13** and approximately **850** views at the end of November.