# December 2021 topic challenge: Elizabeth Moon

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the last SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2021, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the December 2021 topic challenge is going to be devoted to an [American author of sci-fi and fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Moon):

### Elizabeth Moon

### [elizabeth-moon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elizabeth-moon)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during December 2021 we should all try to: either read some Elizabeth Moon stories and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13554/31394). We'll keep a list of all Moon questions asked during December 2021 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Elizabeth Moon answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of December, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Comment: Y'all should read Remnant Population, it's great.

Comment: *Remnant Population* is perhaps my favorite of Moon's works, but I can't think of a good on-topic question about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [In "The Deed of Paksenarrion", what race is the Kuakgan?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/258258/31394) by [Basya](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59154/basya), 16/12/2021.
- [Why is killing a snowcat considered to be "wrong"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258355/why-is-killing-a-snowcat-considered-to-be-wrong) by [just me](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/148142/just-me), 18/12/2021.

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [In "The Deed of Paksenarrion", what race is the Kuakgan?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/258258/31394), with a score of **10** at the end of December.

The **most viewed** is probably [Why is killing a snowcat considered to be "wrong"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/258355/31394), with approximately **140** views during December.