# January 2022 topic challenge: Walter M. Miller Jr

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the first SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2022, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the January 2022 topic challenge is going to be devoted to a [US sci-fi author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_M._Miller_Jr.):

### Walter M. Miller Jr.

### [walter-m-miller-jr](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walter-m-miller-jr)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during January 2022 we should all try to either read some Miller stories and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13582/31394). We'll keep a list of all Miller questions asked during January 2022 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Miller answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of January, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Comment: Took me a moment to figure out who this challenge was about. As far as ISFDB knows he never published anything under his full name Walter Michael Miller Jr.

Comment: Pretty late now, but [here's](https://www.freesfonline.net/authors/Walter%20M._Miller,%20Jr..html) a list of his works freely available online (with links).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [Fiat Voluntas Tua — Are Mrs. Grales & Rachel allegorical characters for Mary and Jesus?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258840/fiat-voluntas-tua-are-mrs-grales-rachel-allegorical-characters-for-mary-and) by [Silly but True](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/145218), 01/01/2022
- [What is the significance of the title "Fiat Voluntas Tua" (a quote from the Latin "Our Father") as a section title in A Canticle for Leibowitz?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258854/what-is-the-significance-of-the-title-fiat-voluntas-tua-a-quote-from-the-lati) by [Buzz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48874), 01/01/2022
- [Is there a listing of all the changes to A Canticle for Leibowitz between the magazine and novel versions?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258874/is-there-a-listing-of-all-the-changes-to-a-canticle-for-leibowitz-between-the-ma) by [Buzz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48874), 02/01/2022
- [Is the original, incomplete manuscript of Saint Leibowitz and the Wild Horse Woman available anywhere?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258891/is-the-original-incomplete-manuscript-of-saint-leibowitz-and-the-wild-horse-wom) by [Buzz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48874), 03/01/2022
- [What fasting laws was Br. Francis subject to?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258992/what-fasting-laws-was-br-francis-subjct-to) by [Buzz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48874), 04/01/2022
- [The electron: "portion" or "torsion" in "Fiat Homo"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259010/the-electron-portion-or-torsion-in-fiat-homo) by [Alfred](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/115682/alfred), 05/01/2022

Honourable mention:

- [Old SF short story where Solarians have evolved into a separate species who eat humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/259869/31394) by [M. A. Golding](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/43538/m-a-golding), 28/01/2022 - an ID question which turned out to be about a Walter M. Miller story.

---

The **highest voted** and **most viewed** of these is [The electron: "portion" or "torsion" in "Fiat Homo"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259010/the-electron-portion-or-torsion-in-fiat-homo), with a score of **12** and approximately **430** views during January.