# March 2022 topic challenge: L. E. Modesitt Jr

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the third SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2022, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the March 2022 topic challenge is going to be devoted to a [US sci-fi and fantasy author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._E._Modesitt_Jr.):

### L. E. Modesitt Jr.

### [l-e-modesitt-jr](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l-e-modesitt-jr)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during March 2022 we should all try to either read some Modesitt stories and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13631/31394). We'll keep a list of all Modesitt questions asked during March 2022 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Modesitt answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of March, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [Do any of L.E. Modesitt's worlds cross over?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261214/do-any-of-l-e-modesitts-worlds-cross-over) by [Bobson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5490/bobson), 14/03/2022.
- [Is there a definitive Recluce timeline?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261458) by [Bobson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5490/bobson), 21/03/2022.

---

Both of them had a score of **3** at the end of March, and almost the same number of views too, but [Do any of L.E. Modesitt's worlds cross over?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/261214/31394) just edged it out as the **most viewed** with approximately **68** views during March.