# April 2022 topic challenge: Neverwhere

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the fourth SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2022, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the April 2022 topic challenge is going to be devoted to a [work of fantasy writer Neil Gaiman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwhere_(disambiguation)):

### *Neverwhere*

### [neverwhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neverwhere)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during April 2022 we should all try to either read/watch/consume (in whatever medium) *Neverwhere* and ask interesting questions about it, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13645/31394). We'll keep a list of all *Neverwhere* questions asked during April 2022 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Neverwhere answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of April, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Comment: Purely as an aside, there are multiple (legitimate) copies of Neverwhere that can be dowloaded from the archive.com library; [Here](https://archive.org/details/neverwhere0000gaim_j7v6), [here](https://archive.org/details/neverwhere0000gaim) and [here](https://archive.org/details/neverwhereauthor0000gaim)

Comment: @Valorum The legitimacy of archive.org's "lending library" is frequently disputed ([Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Library#Copyright_violation_accusations)). While it probably doesn't open individual users up to legal challenge, they might want to consider the _ethics_ of reading a digital copy that has not been authorised by the copyright holder.

Comment: @IMSoP - I'm not entirely sure I'm on the ethical side of the billionaires suing a library for being too successful in lending books.

Comment: @Valorum Well, that's the same defence as "I use Napster because music publishers are corrupt", or "I use BitTorrent because movie distributors are corrupt" - it's saying that by-passing the official channels is _justified_ rather than that it's _legitimate_. If I was an author trying to sell e-books, I don't think I'd be very happy to find people making copies available for free.

Comment: Authors have hated libraries since time immemorial.

Comment: @IMSoP Gaiman himself [isn't too sad](https://dh.sunygeneseoenglish.org/2014/04/30/neil-gaiman-the-author-who-improved-piracy/) about his books being pirated online. To summarise, he thinks it works for introducing people to new things, as well as a referral system for reading an author's future work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bneverwhere%5D+created%3A2022-04-01..2022-04-30+is%3Aq) as part of this topic challenge**

- [Differences between BBC TV serial and novel of Neverwhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/261851/31394) by [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez), 01/04/2022.
- [How did Hunter save Richard's life three times crossing Knightsbridge?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/262223/31394) by [杜興怡](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/550/%e6%9d%9c%e8%88%88%e6%80%a1), 14/04/2022.
- [The German translation of Neverwhere, or something else?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/262241/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394), 14/04/2022.
- [What are the names of the Seven Sisters?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/262276/31394) by [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez), 16/04/2022.
- [Which tube station did Varney die in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/262332/31394) by [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez), 19/04/2022.

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [The German translation of Neverwhere, or something else?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/262241/31394), with a score of **15** at the end of April.

The **most viewed** is probably [What are the names of the Seven Sisters?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/262276/31394), which had over 1600 views by the end of the year. (I forgot to update this post at the end of April.)