# May 2022 topic challenge: Cliff McNish

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the fifth SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2022, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the May 2022 topic challenge is going to be devoted to [an English fantasy writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliff_McNish):

### Cliff McNish

### [cliff-mcnish](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cliff-mcnish)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during May 2022 we should all try to either read some Cliff McNish stories and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13666/31394). We'll keep a list of all Cliff McNish questions asked during May 2022 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Cliff McNish answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of May, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [To what extent Is Rachel in The Doomspell based on the author's real life daughter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263436/to-what-extent-is-rachel-in-the-doomspell-based-on-the-authors-real-life-daught) by [Showsni](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/118557/showsni), 20/05/2022.

---

It had a score of **4** at the end of May, and at most **50** views during May. (These stats added in December, so an exact view count for May is impossible to get now.)