# June 2022 topic challenge: Naomi Novik

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the sixth SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2022, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the June 2022 topic challenge is going to be devoted to [an American speculative fiction writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naomi_Novik):

### Naomi Novik

### [naomi-novik](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naomi-novik)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during June 2022 we should all try to either read some Naomi Novik stories and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13704/58193). We'll keep a list of all Naomi Novik questions asked during June 2022 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Naomi Novik answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of June, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [Why is Agnieszka so untidy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264034/why-is-agnieszka-so-untidy) by [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez), 06/06/2022.
- [Temeraire Series and colonisation of North America](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264159/temeraire-series-and-colonisation-of-north-america) by [Jontia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40437/jontia), 09/06/2022.

---

The **highest-voted** and **most viewed** of these is [Why is Agnieszka so untidy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264034/why-is-agnieszka-so-untidy), with a score of **12** at the end of June and at most 328 views during June (impossible to get an exact view count figure as this info added in December).