# July 2022 Topic Challenge: Nnedi Okorafor

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the seventh SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2022, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the July 2022 topic challenge is going to be devoted to [a Nigerian-American science fiction and fantasy writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nnedi_Okorafor):

### Nnedi Okorafor

### [nnedi-okorafor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nnedi-okorafor)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during July 2022 we should all try to either read some Nnedi Okorafor stories and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13734/58193). We'll keep a list of all Nnedi Okorafor questions asked during July 2022 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Nnedi Okorafor answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of July, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Comment: Note: I've let the topic challenge run for a few extra days because we forgot to start it in time.

Comment: I wonder whether it would be worth running it over 2 months, July + August. This was done with at least one of the challenges last year, to compensate for reduced interest during the summer holidays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [What is the source of the chittim?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265268/what-is-the-source-of-the-chittim/) by [Adamant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51379/adamant), 09/07/2022
- [How is Remote Control connected to Ginen?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265269/how-is-remote-control-connected-to-ginen) by [Adamant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51379/adamant), 09/07/2022
- [What were the objects in the House of Power?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265279/what-were-the-objects-in-the-house-of-power) by [Adamant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51379/adamant), 09/07/2022
- [Were AO's abilities intended or not?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265329/were-aos-abilities-intended-or-not) by [Adamant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51379/adamant),  10/07/2022
- [Has Okorafor commented on the meaning of the protagonists' names?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265331/has-okorafor-commented-on-the-meaning-of-the-protagonists-names) by [Adamant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51379/adamant), 10/07/2022
- [What did people believe to be the cause of the Red Eye?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265339/what-did-people-believe-to-be-the-cause-of-the-red-eye) by [Adamant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51379/adamant), 10/07/2022
- [What is Loppa hair?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266173/what-is-loppa-hair/) by [AncientSwordRage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804/ancientswordrage), 01/08/2022.
- [Who is Baba Sola?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266303/who-is-baba-sola) by [Adamant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51379/adamant), 04/08/2022

---

The **highest-voted** and **most viewed** of these is [What is the source of the chittim?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265268/what-is-the-source-of-the-chittim/), with a score of **5** at the end of July and at most 162 views during July (view figure not exact as this info added in December).