# August 2022 topic challenge: Madeleine L'Engle's Time Quintet

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the eighth SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2022, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the August 2022 topic challenge is going to be devoted to [a series of "science fantasy" novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Quintet):

### The Time Quintet (*A Wrinkle in Time* and sequels)

(so far the tag is [a-wrinkle-in-time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-wrinkle-in-time), not sure if that needs to be changed or not)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during August 2022 we should all try to either read one or more of the Time Quintet stories and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13743/31394). We'll keep a list of all Time Quintet questions asked during August 2022 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Time Quintet answer has been deleted from that thread at the start of August, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Comment: Are new answers to old questions on the topic, included in the topic challenge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [What in what collections have the books of the Time Quintet been released?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266424) by [Buzz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48874), 07/08/2022.
- [What is the origin of the name "Megatron"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266641/what-is-the-origin-of-the-name-megatron) by [Buzz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48874), 13/08/2022.
- [Why have later books in the Wrinkle in Time series never got much attention or been adapted?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/266965/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394), 23/08/2022.

---

The **highest-voted** and **most viewed** of these is [Why have later books in the Wrinkle in Time series never got much attention or been adapted?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/266965/31394), with a score of **12** at the end of August and approximately **3000** views during August (between 2500, as the Notable Question badge was awarded on 25 August, and 3100, its view count in January).

---

**List of all answers to existing questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

[Answer to "Tessering by what means in 'Wrinkle'?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/267128/59154) by [Basya](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59154/basya), 29/08/2022.