# Are new answers to existing questions included in the topic challenge?

Tags: discussion

The topic challenge is described as follows (see [this month's topic challenge](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/august-2022-topic-challenge-madeleine-lengles-time-quintet)):

> we should all try to either read one or more of the Time Quintet
> stories and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by
> answering other people's questions about them.

Later in the description it says:

> We'll keep a list of all Time Quintet questions asked during August
> 2022 in an answer to this meta post.

What about *answers* to preexisting questions, on the topic, which were added in answer to the topic challenge?  For example, I added [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/267128/59154) as I was looking at questions with the a-wrinkle-in-time tag, hoping to find something to answer on the topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't something we need to have very strict rules about.

It wouldn't make sense to include such an answer in the list of *questions* asked during the topic challenge, but would be fine to add another section below that to list new answers posted to old questions. Feel free to edit the topic challenge collection answers on meta; they're all CW to make them easier for anyone to edit.

Answer (score 2):

The lawyer in me says 'no'. We have a rule and your answer clearly falls outside the bounds. It's not a new question.

In reality, this is an internal competition with no actual prizes. I'm sure if you ask @Randal'Thor, he'll pencil in an '*honourable mention'* for you.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not a lawyer :-) :-)

Comment: You are correct that it is an internal competition with no actual prizes.   I was still curious.  I am very fond of (some of) these books, and reread them to try to come up with a question, but didn't manage to!  So I looked to see what I could answer.  An interesting case, in my opinion, since it is a result which seems to fit the *intent* of the topic challenge, but not the "letter of the law" as it is written....