# September 2022 topic challenge: the Deryni series

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the ninth SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2022, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the September 2022 topic challenge is going to be devoted to [a historical fantasy series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deryni_novels):

### The Deryni series

[deryni-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deryni-series)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during September 2022 we should all try to either read one or more of the Deryni books and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13761/31394). We'll keep a list of all Deryni questions asked during September 2022 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Vote on future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Deryni answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of September, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bderyni-series%5D+is%3Aq+created%3A2022-09-01..2022-09-30) as part of this topic challenge**

- [Who is the Supreme of Howicce, from "Deryni Rising?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267274/59154) by [Basya](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59154/basya)
- [Who is the nearest neighbor of Corwyn?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267430/who-is-the-nearest-neighbor-of-corwyn) by [Basya](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59154/basya)
- [How does it come about that Jehana acquires such Deryni hatred in Bremagne?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267515/how-does-it-come-about-that-jehana-acquires-such-deryni-hatred-in-bremagne) by [Basya](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59154/basya)
- [How was Kevin's death connected to the Deryni issue?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267525/59154) by [Basya](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59154/basya)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Who is the Supreme of Howicce, from "Deryni Rising?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267274/59154), with a score of **4** at the end of September.

The **most viewed** is probably [How was Kevin's death connected to the Deryni issue?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267525/31394), with at most 102 views during September. (These figures added in January, so it's impossible now to get exact view counts for the month of September.)