# Topic Challenge: House of the Dragon

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the tenth SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2022, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. This topic challenge is going to be slightly different in that it isn't coming from the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394) but rather than for a recently finished TV series:

### House of the Dragon

[house-of-the-dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-the-dragon)

For such a large and popular show it is criminal we only have 3 questions in the tag at the time of writing. As such I am personally going to award several bounties to content posted within the topic challenge.

Questions about *Fire & Blood* or *A Song of Ice and Fire* as it relates to the period in *House of the Dragon* are also accepted within this challenge.

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during the challenge we should all try to either watch the series and ask interesting questions about it, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13793/58193). We'll keep a list of all House of the Dragon questions asked during the challenge in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the challenge, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc.

This challenge is going to run through to the end of November.

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Vote on future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

Comment: Maybe there were only three questions because the first episode of the show had only been released about two months previously. I thought the topic challenge was supposed to draw attention to lesser-known works, not extremely famous franchises.

Comment: @Adamant meant to draw attention to works with little content on the site. That tends to be lesser known works but doesn’t necessarily mean it always is. Also you’re more likely to get questions as it’s airing not afterwards so the first two months should be the busiest.

Comment: It's large and popular but that doesn't mean it's any good. It's an extremely famous franchise that's been struggling ever since it went from that episode where you couldn't see shit to where everything was on fire, including their own IP. *Why isn't his brother in line for the throne?*

Answer (score 2):

**List of [all questions posted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhouse-of-the-dragon%5D+is%3Aq+created%3A2022-10-26..2022-11-30) as part of this topic challenge**

- [What could cause the bond between a dragon and its rider to be broken, other than death?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/268906/58193) by [galacticninja](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7957/galacticninja), 26/10/2022.
- [Who was Prince Viserys Targaryen (brother of Daenerys) named after?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/269103/58193) by [galacticninja](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7957/galacticninja), 02/11/2022.
- *add entries in the form `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/mm/2022.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[question URL]*, with a score of *TBD* at the end of November.

The **most viewed** is *[question URL]*, with approximately *TBD* views during November.