# December 2022 Topic Challenge: Trudi Canavan

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the eleventh SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2022, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the December 2022 topic challenge is going to be devoted to [an Australian fantasy author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trudi_Canavan):

### Trudi Canavan

[trudi-canavan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trudi-canavan)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during December 2022 we should all try to either read one or more of Trudi's books and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13806/58193). We'll keep a list of all Trudi Canavan questions asked during December 2022 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Vote on future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Trudi Canavan answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of December, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Comment: I briefly thought this was going to be about a different Australian Trudy who produces fantasy content.

Answer (score 4):

**List of [all questions posted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btrudi-canavan%5D+is%3Aq+created%3A2022-12-01..2022-12-30) as part of this topic challenge**

- [How old (long) is the Age of Five](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270181/how-old-long-is-the-age-of-five) by [Jontia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40437/jontia), 12/12/2022.
- [Creation of Siyee and Elai](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/270551/31394) by [Jontia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40437/jontia), 24/12/2022.
- [Any real-world inspiration for the countries in the Black Magician series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/270568/31394) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394), 25/12/2022.

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [How old (long) is the Age of Five](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270181/how-old-long-is-the-age-of-five), with a score of **5** at the end of December.

The **most viewed** is [Any real-world inspiration for the countries in the Black Magician series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/270568/31394), with approximately **85** views during December.