# January 2023 topic challenge: Janni Lee Simner

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the first SFF.SE **topic challenge** of 2023, in which the site's community is encouraged to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the January 2023 topic challenge is going to be devoted to a [US fantasy author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janni_Lee_Simner):

### Janni Lee Simner

### [janni-lee-simner](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/janni-lee-simner)

---

**What's a topic challenge and how do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during January 2023 we should all try to either read some Simner stories and ask interesting questions about them, or help out by *answering* other people's questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13827/31394). We'll keep a list of all Simner questions asked during January 2023 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted).

Note that Simner has published a lot of short stories as well as novels, some of which are [freely available online](https://www.freesfonline.net/authors/Janni%20Lee_Simner.html), which makes this a relatively approachable topic challenge - you don't need to invest money in buying books or time in reading long ones; it's possible to dip in and read a few short stories before deciding if she's an author you like or not.

---

**What's next?**

Future topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Vote on future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The Simner answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of January, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Answer (score 3):

**List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [In "Faerie After", why was Karin (before her mother's death) less able to function than Toby](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/271750/59154), by [Basya](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59154/basya), 1/31/2023
- [In "Faerie After", why did Karin make the final decision she did?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/271749/59154), by [Basya](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59154/basya), 1/31/2023
- [In *Bones of Faerie*, what happened with Rebecca's shadow and her mother, Tara?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/271096/59154) by [Basya](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59154/basya), 1/11/2023
- [In "Invasive Species", why are the trees angry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270790/in-invasive-species-why-are-the-trees-angry) by [Basya](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59154/basya), 01/01/2023
- *add entries in the form `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/01/2023.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[question URL]*, with a score of *TBD* at the end of January.

The **most viewed** is *[question URL]*, with approximately *TBD* views during January.